# resize external images from other websites before loading them?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Iam working on  a project , which involves fetching images from various websites and displaying a Thumnail or resized version of orignal image.
As i will be fetching many images at time , this takes more time , As Orignal image files will be loaded.

**What i need is given an image url ,  i need  resized version of that image file? So that i need not download the Large orignal image file...**

for example :
 orignal image : 500X800  some 500kb
              what i need is : 100X150 some 100kb image file..
Is it possible using Jquery? OR PHP?
Are their any functions like imagecopyresampled(PHP) in Jquery or any plugins?

Comment: You have to use PHP. JQuery has no way to alter the actual file size of the image.

Comment: You are asking the host server to resize it so no, that's not possible unless you have authority over the server. Unless host server provides such resizing options

Comment: You will ALWAYS download the image to your server if you use PHP and to client computer if you use JS before you resize it if you don't own the remote server.

Comment: Vamsi, was your question answered?  Is there something that you would want more explanation on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**PHP Thumb**](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) is a good plugin it worked for me and easy to operate.
And the best part is there are **many options to select** about the output file like its **quality**, **max width for potrait images** , **max width for landscape images** etc..
And we can set permissions like **block off server requests**, **block off domain thumbnails**.. etc

Note: this was actually posted by someone , as an answer to this question..But it was deleted.So iam reposting it, as it was useful.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the big file needs to be downloaded at one point to create the thumbnail.

What you can do, through JQuery, is ask your server for the thumbnail, the server downloads the file, creates the thumbnail and sends back to the client the URL of the thumbnail when the resizing is done. This way, the client will gradually receive thumbnails as they are ready.

**Edit** After experimenting a bit, I found out that as soon as an `img` requests a picture, even if you dynamically remove its `src` attribute, the download continue.

So I decided to write a sample code (there's not much validation and it only works for jpeg, adding the other types would be really easy though). The solution is divided in 3 parts:

**HTML**

First, I used an empty `div` with some specific attributes to let `jQuery` what to load. I need to apologize to Nuria Oliver, she had the first "big picture" I could find on the net. So, here's a sample `div`:

```
<div class="thumbnail" data-source="http://www.nuriaoliver.com/pics/nuria1.jpg" data-thumbnail-width="100" data-thumbnail-height= "200"/></div>
```

I use `thumbnail` as `class` to be able to find easily the divs I want. The other `data` parameters allow me to configure the thumbnail with the `source`, `width` and `height`.

**JavaScript / jQuery**

Now, we need to locate all these `div`s requesting `thumbnail`s... using jQuery it is pretty easy.  We extract all the `data` settings and push them in an array. We then feed a `PHP` page with the query and wait for the response. While doing so, I'm filling the `div` with some HTML showing the "progress"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".thumbnail").each(function() {
        var img = $(this);
        var thumbnailWidth = img.data("thumbnail-width");
        var thumbnailHeight = img.data("thumbnail-height");
        var thumbnailSource = img.data("source");

        var innerDiv = "<div style='width:" + thumbnailWidth + "px; height:" + thumbnailHeight + "px'>Loading Thumbnail<br><img src='loading.gif'></div>"; 
        img.html(innerDiv); // replace with placeholder

        var thumbnailParams = {};
        thumbnailParams['src'] = thumbnailSource;
        thumbnailParams['width'] = thumbnailWidth;
        thumbnailParams['height'] = thumbnailHeight;

        $.ajax({
            url: "imageloader.php",
            data: thumbnailParams,
            success: function(data) {
                img.html("<img src='" + data + "'>");
            },
        });
    })
</script>
```

**PHP**

On the `PHP` side of things, I do a quick test to see if the picture has already been cached (I'm only using the file name, this should be more complicated but it was just to give you an example) otherwise I download the picture, resize it, store it in a `thumbnail` folder and return the path to `jQuery`:

```
<?php

$url = $_GET["src"];
$width = $_GET["width"];
$height = $_GET["height"];

$filename = "thumbnail/" . basename($url);
if(is_file($filename)) // File is already cached
{
    echo $filename;
    exit;
}

// for now only assume JPG, but checking the extention should be easy to support other types
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($url)); // download large picture
list($originalWidth, $originalHeight) = getimagesize($filename);
$original = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); // load original file
$thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); // create thumbnail
imagecopyresized($thumbnail, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $originalWidth, $originalHeight); // copy the thumbnail
imagedestroy($original);
imagejpeg($thumbnail, $filename); // overwrite existing file
imagedestroy($thumbnail);
echo $filename;
```

**Browser**

So, what does it do exactly?  In the Browser, when I open the page I first see:

[image: loading]

And as soon as the server is done processing the image, it gets updated automatically to:

[image: loaded]

Which is a thumbnail version, `100x200` of our original picture.

I hope this covers everything you needed!

Comment: Either way you've got to download the image, this is probably the best way to do it with a script, but still, if you're going to do that, why not just just use CSS and define the size in the `<img>` tag. That way it will still hold the image's place while it's downloading.

Answer (score 0):

for this to work you need to do some actual image processing which you cant do with js, so some server side language is needed.PHP is an option

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interesting in obfuscating the image source, you may very well rely on an external tool like http://images.weserv.nl/ which takes an [original image](http://www.google.nl/logos/logo.gif) and allows you to [request it in a different size](http://images.weserv.nl/?url=www.google.nl/logos/logo.gif&h=45).

If you end up *not* relying on a global CDN, at least sort out proper caching. Last thing you want to do is resize the same image over and over again for subsequent identical requests - any benefit of image's lower size will probably be negated by processing time.